# Testcontainers does not run FTP container

Tags: java, spring-boot, testcontainers

I am trying to deploy a testcontainer in Java with an FTP,

```
private final static ImageFromDockerfile imageDockerFile = new ImageFromDockerfile().withFileFromClasspath("Dockerfile",
                                                                                                             "ftp_container/Dockerfile")
                                                                                      .withFileFromClasspath("vsftp.conf",
                                                                                                             "ftp_container/vsftp.conf")
                                                                                      .withFileFromClasspath("start.sh",
                                                                                                             "ftp_container/start.sh");


  public FtpContainer()
  {
    super(imageDockerFile);
    withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("ftp_container/vsftp.conf"),
                            "etc/vsftp/vsftp.conf");
    withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("ftp_container/start.sh"),
                            "/start.sh");
    withCommand("ftp");
  }
```

And it starts without problems, but the container does not appear and I can't connect to the container

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssl vsftpd && rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash admin && echo 'admin:admin' | chpasswd

COPY vsftp.conf /etc/vsftp/vsftp.conf
COPY start.sh /

RUN chmod +x /start.sh
RUN mkdir -p /home/vsftpd/
RUN chown -R ftp:ftp /home/vsftpd/

VOLUME /home/admin
VOLUME /var/log/vsftpd

EXPOSE 21

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

EDIT: I add my start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

CONF_FILE="/etc/vsftp/vsftp.conf"

echo "Launching vsftp on ftp protocol"

&>/dev/null /usr/sbin/vsftpd $CONF_FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

If container "does not appear" it can mean three things:

1. There is some issue with configuration of testcontainers (in the code). In this case the chances are that you'll see an exception in Java, I assume its not your case
2. The `start.sh` was triggered but for some reason the process has died and the docker container itself died. In this case, Place a breakpoint in the right after the test container code (before the code that actually uses it) and once you get to that breakpoint Run `docker ps`. The chances are that the container won't be there. Then try to understand from `docker ps -a` whether there was a "recently-died" container and what do its logs show? (you can try to put an `echo hello` in start.sh to check that it gets printed to stdout and fetched by docker logs command)
3. The start.sh starts some kind of server but it takes time till it gets started. I saw this happening for some kinds of containers (it pretty much depends how the `start.sh` is written). In this case do the same trick with a breakpoint but this time when you run `docker ps` you should see the docker process up and running. 
   Try to wait for a while and "continue" the test execution. If you see that the test works now, you can either rewrite the startup script so that it won't return will the service is ready (port can receive connections) or add an "artificial" wait in the code (Yeah, I know this sounds bad, but sometimes you can't tough a container so its your only choice).

Comment: Okey, I'll try seeing it with echo hello and docker ps. Thanks!

Comment: So it maps to the case "2" of my answer, right? Was there an attempt to run it ? What does "docker ps -a" show?

Comment: It exits with Exit 0, in the comment bellow I show my start.sh

Comment: You should edit your question, not add an answer, because its not really an answer :) Anyway, this means that leave alone the testcontainers, the docker image you create also is supposed to exit with 0 immediately, right? In this case I suggest to  try to build the image (with docker build command) and start from the command line before you start playing with testcontainers... I suspect its something from with config file, but I'm not familiar with this concrete ftp server so I can't really comment on that

Comment: I tried also building the image and does not work. Do you know another ftp server to put into testcontainers?

Comment: Quick googling reveals https://github.com/stilliard/docker-pure-ftpd, but you should try by yourself, really, I don't really have an "immediate" answer for this up on my sleeves

Comment: I tried also, but it returns me always the error: Server replied with: 500 I won't open a connection to 127.0.0.1 (only to 172.17.0.1)